# Calculating conditional probability from joint probability distribution table

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am working on the following homework problem, given the table below:

```
| a | b | c | p(a,b,c) |
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:--------:|
| 0 | 0 | 0 |   0.192  |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |   0.144  |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |   0.048  |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |   0.216  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |   0.192  |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |   0.064  |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |   0.048  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |   0.096  |
```

> a) Determine whether *a* and *b* are independent: `p(a ∩ b) = p(a)p(b)`
>
> b) Determine whether *a* and *b* are conditionally independent on *c*: `p(a ∩ b | c) = p(a | c)p(b | c)`

My thought process was below:

1. First, the probability of `a` and `b`

`p(a) = all values where a = 1`
`p(a) = 0.192 + 0.064 + 0.048 + 0.096 = 0.4`

`p(b) = all values where b = 1`
`p(b) = 0.048 + 0.216 + 0.048 + 0.096 = 0.408`

2. First, the probability of p(a ∩ b)

`p(a ∩ b) = all values where a = 1 and b = 1`
`p(a ∩ b) = 0.048 + 0.096 = 0.144`

3. Compare values
   `0.144 = ((0.4)(0.408)) = NOT TRUE`

**Therefore, a and b are dependent events**

Now, moving onto `b)`:

1. Calculate all relevant values:

`p(a) = all values where a = 1`
`p(a) = 0.192 + 0.064 + 0.048 + 0.096 = 0.4`

`p(b) = all values where b = 1`
`p(b) = 0.048 + 0.216 + 0.048 + 0.096 = 0.408`

`p(c) = all values where c = 1`
`p(c) = 0.144 + 0.216 + 0.064 + 0.096 = 0.52`

`p(a,c) = all values where a = 1 and c = 1`
`p(a,c) = 0.064 + 0.096 = 0.16`
`p(a|c) = 0.16 / 0.52 = 0.31`

`p(b, c) = all values where b = 1 and c = 1`
`p(b, c) = 0.216 + 0.096 = 0.312`
`p(b|c) = 0.312 / 0.52 = 0.6`

Thus `p(a|c)p(b|c) = (0.31)(0.6) = 0.119`

Knowing `p(a,b,c) = 0.192`, then `0.192 / 0.52 = 0.369`

**Therefore we know that a and b are not conditionally independent given the values of c**

> Therefore, my questions are:
>
> 1. Is this work correct? If not, what is wrong?
> 2. Why am I using a/b/c = 1 instead of 0?

Comment: If you want to show that two random variables are independent, you need to show that the equality holds for every point in the joint support. However, when you find that the equality does not hold for one particular point, it will be a counter example, and it will be sufficient to claim that they are dependent. In addition, your case is a special case as the random variables are binary, and thus $X = 0$ and $X = 1$ are complementary events, and it is sufficient to check one of those point $(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)$ to show that they are dependent / independent.

Comment: Understood, so the selection of either `x = 0` or `x = 1` does not matter. However, were the calculations performed correctly? The reason I am concerned is that I found an online answer, which I don't like using, that argues in b) they *are* conditionally independent (https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/83-consider-three-binary-variables-b-c-e-0-1-joint-distribution-given-table-82-show-direct-q23435474)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us convert first, the given information in the table to given probabilities

P(a) = 0.192+0.064+0.048+0.096 = 0.4

P(b)= 0.048+0.216+0.048+0.096 = 0.408

P(c) = 0.144+0.216+0.064+0.096 = 0.52

Consider  p(a ∩ b) = p(a)p(b) = 0.4*0.408= 0.1632  ...... (1)

But P(a ∩ b) = 0.048+0.096= 0.144 ....... (2) (From the table)

Since (1) and (2) are not equal, we conclude that a and b are not

independent.

Consider now p(a ∩ b/c) = p(a∩b∩c)/P(c)= 0.096/0.52 = 0.185...(3)

Consider P(a/c) = p(a∩c)/P(c)=(0.064+0.096)/0.52 = 0.16/0.52 = 0.308

Consider P(b/c) = p(b∩c)/P(c)=(0.216+0.096)/0.52 = 0.312/0.52 = 0.0.6

So, P(a/c)*P(b/c) = 0.308*0.6 = 0.1848 = 0.185 .... (4)

Since (3) and (4) are equal, we can say that

p(a ∩ b | c) = p(a | c)p(b | c)

So, a and b are conditionally independent on c